# How to change number of non-numeric x axis ticks in Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to set custom ticks for a seaborn plot but it shows only half of the ticks. How do I increase the number of ticks for non-numeric values?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns    
df_x = pd.DataFrame({'Period': list(range(1,13)),
                           '2016': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2017': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12),
                           '2018': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=12)}) 

df_x.set_index('Period', inplace=True)
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_x[['2016','2017','2018']])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan'])
```

I would like to see the ticks exactly in the order I listed.

Python 3.7.1, Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Try setting the number of xticks. `ax.set_xticks(range(0,12))`

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the number of tick marks:

```
ax.set_xticks(range(0,12))
```